# ArangoDB: Find all shortest paths with conditions

Tags: arangodb, aql

problem: I have a start node and i am searching for nodes with a certain property. But i want only the nodes connected with the shortest ones.

Example: The green nodes have the property set, but i want only "A" and "C" back, because "E" has a longer path

[image: graph]

What ive got so far:

```
LET source = (FOR x IN Entity FILTER x.objectID == @nodeId
    return x)[0]
FOR node, edge, path IN 1..5 ANY source._id GRAPH 'm' 
 FILTER CONTAINS(node.label,  @search)
  LIMIT @limit
  RETURN path
```

but this returns everything instead of only the shortest paths

Answer (score 0):

You can get the distance from the origin node using `LENGTH(path.edges)`, so if you put the traversal into a subquery you can find the shortest path length afterward and then filter by that length:

```
LET allMatches = (
  FOR node, edge, path IN 1..3 ANY "[vertex_id]" GRAPH "[my_graph]"
    FILTER CONTAINS(node.label,  @search)
    LIMIT @limit
    RETURN {node,path})
LET shortestPathLength = MIN(FOR m IN allMatches COLLECT len = LENGTH(m.edges) RETURN len)
FOR m IN allMatches
  FILTER LENGTH(m.path.edges) == shortestPathLength
  RETURN m.node
```

There might be a nicer way to do this in one query (e.g. doing a breadth-first traversal and then getting it to stop somehow) but I'm not seeing it.